# Flutter: display dynamic list

Tags: flutter

I've got a widget that displays a classes' list, but that list changes (the content changes) over time by other elements and interactions of the program. How can the `DisplayListWidget` detect this? Do the elements that change this list have to communicate with the `displaylistwidget`?

EDIT: I'm familiair with stateful widgets and `setState () {}`. It's just that the data changes in the background (e.g. by a  timer) so there's no reference from bussiness logic classes to widgets to even call setState.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to notify (rebuild) widgets when data changes, check out [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package.

There are some other options:

- `BLoC` (Business Logic Component) design pattern.
- [mobx](https://pub.dev/packages/mobx)
- [Redux](https://pub.dev/packages/redux)

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Try wrapping the display widget in a state widget, and then whenever you update the list, call `setState(() { //update list here })`

ex.

```
// this is the widget that you'd nest directly into the rest of your tree
class FooList extends StatefulWidget {
    FooListState createState() => FooListState();
}

// this is the state you will want to call setState on
class FooListState extends State<FooList> {
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return DisplayListWidget [...]
   }
}
```

I would recommend following [this](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab) flutter tutorial where they [dynamically update a list](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/codelab#step-4-create-an-infinite-scrolling-listview)

And to learn more about StatefulWidgets and States check this out: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html